# python bit operation issue

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

i'm having an issue with bitwise operations and wanted to know if it's ther is an operator where it always returns me a 0. I put an example:

I want an operator '?' where:

```
0b000 ? 0b100 = 0b000
0b100 ? 0b100 = 0b000
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the use of such an "operator"?

Comment: I want an operator that does both opreations

Comment: Both? What do you mean?

Comment: Multiplication? `0b100 * 0 = 0`? (but WTF is that for‽)

Comment: Why not just forget about the first number and  use 0 directly?

Answer (score 0):

There is ***no `?` bit-wise operator which just returns 0***.

These are ***pythons bit-wise operators*** :

1. **x << y** Returns x with the bits shifted to the left by y places (and new bits on the right-hand-side are zeros). This is the same as
   multiplying x by 2**y.
2. **x >> y** Returns x with the bits shifted to the right by y places. This is the same as //'ing x by 2**y.
3. **x & y** Does a "bitwise and". Each bit of the output is 1 if the corresponding bit of x AND of y is 1, otherwise it's 0.
4. **x | y** Does a "bitwise or". Each bit of the output is 0 if the corresponding bit of x AND of y is 0, otherwise it's 1.
5. **~ x** Returns the complement of x - the number you get by switching each 1 for a 0 and each 0 for a 1. This is the same as -x- 1.
6. **x ^ y** Does a "bitwise exclusive or". Each bit of the output is the same as the corresponding bit in x if that bit in y is 0, and
   it's the complement of the bit in x if that bit in y is 1.

Source [Bitwise operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)